# Geodjango transform introduces large errors

Tags: coordinate-system, geodjango

Apologies for the possibly naive question.  I'm trying to understand how Geodjango (running on PostGIS) deals with coordinate transformations, and am experiencing some unusual behaviour.

Let's say I have a very simple model with a geometry field, with SRID 27700 (OSGB):

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
class MyGeoClass(models.Model):
    point = models.PointField(srid=27700)
```

I create an entry in this coordinate ref system:

```
from django.contrib.gis import geos
m = MyGeoClass(point=geos.Point([527860, 184660], srid=27700))
m.save()
```

Now, if I load the entry and transform it to a different coordinate system and back again, it introduces a slight error

```
m = MyGeoClass.objects.all()[0]
m.point.coords
>>> (527860.0, 184660.0)
m.point.transform(4326)
m.point.transform(27700)
m.point.coords
>>> (527860.0007865971, 184659.99966225715)
```

No surprise there - I guess this is just numerical rounding error.  But if I instead leave the point in SRID 4326 and issue a `save()` call, Geodjango automatically transforms it for me, with a much larger error:

```
m = MyGeoClass.objects.all()[0]
m.point.coords
>>> (527860.0, 184660.0)
m.point.transform(4326)
m.save()    
m = MyGeoClass.objects.all()[0]
m.point.srid
>>> 27700
m.point.coords
>>> (527861.48656512, 184654.1590452015)
```

So, the transform-transform pathway introduces an error of around 0.001 metres, whereas the transform-save pathway introduces an error of 1.4 metres in the x-dimension and 5 metres in the y dimension.

Comment: Since no one has answered, should I raise a ticket with the Django developers?